# RIDE run pluggin not working

Tags: ubuntu, robotframework

I've recently downloaded RIDE on Ubuntu for Robot Framework testing. However, I am unable to use the run plugin properly. "Edit" and "Text Edit" work fine, and the check boxes for "Test Runner," and "Run Anything" are clicked. But when I click the run tab, nothing happens. Pressing f8 allows tests to be run, but I would prefer to modify arguments more easily.
Especially since there is an extra argument in the pybot command that I need to remove in order to test my program more efficiently.

> command: pybot a --argumentfile /tmp/RIDEzeOnoi.d/argfile.txt
>   --listener /home/noah/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotide/contrib/testrunner/TestRunnerAgent.py:41457:False
>   /home/noah/robotframework/HelloWorld.robot [ ERROR ] Parsing 'a'
>   failed: Data source does not exist.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the "a" supposed to be after the word `pybot`? It looks like you've misconfigured the way RIDE is supposed to run the pybot command.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there was an issue created with this question [here](https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/issues/1750)

To reproduce your problem I had to provoke it by adding an 'a' to the robotarguments. So, you just have to delete that 'a' from the Arguments field.